# How to get IP adress of machine(on Linux) in AP mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am Configuring my board in Wi-Fi AP mode. I am able to see wlan AP interface using *ifconfig*

```
 ifconfig wlan1
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:DA:EA:C2:63:17  
          inet addr:192.168.43.1  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:eaff:fec2:6317%767480/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:12808 (12.5 KiB)
```

I have Linux 4.4 running on my board. Is there any API through which i can get the ip address of board i.e. **192.168.43.1** .

I want to write a c application which will use this IP address. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ioctl` with SIOCGIFADDR will help.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of linux, there are multiple ways to get the IP address of interface using a C program.

1. `ioctl` - This is supported in linux for configuring or fetching information about the network devices. You can use ioctl commands that operate on interfaces such as `SIOCGIFADDR` for fetching IP address of interface and `SIOCGIFNETMASK` to get the interface netmask.
2. `getifaddrs` - This can be used for fetching the IP address of the interface. Refer to the link http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html which carries a wonderful example.